# Maximizing the number of zero entries in a linear combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

I was wondering if there exists an algorithmic way of solving the following problem. Let's say you have a bunch of square $N\times N$ matrices (call them $M_i$), and you want to form a linear combination of them such that the final matrix has the maximum possible number of zero entries.

$\tilde{M}=\sum_i c_iM_i$

The matrices $M_i$ are hermitian, and let the only restriction on your $c_i$'s be that they can't be zero. They can be complex numbers though. I am looking for a general way that doesn't depend on the specific form of the $M_i$'s. Any input on how to do this, or any idea on how to start thinking about this is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each matrix with a column vector of its entries (i.e., the first col, atop the second, atop the third, and so on). Now you have a problem of finding a linear combination of vectors with the most zeroes. That SHOULD be a standard linear programming problem, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes, isn't it an isomorphism?

Comment: It is. But if you want to look for algorithms related to this topic, searching for "vectors with lots of zeroes" is likely to get you more than "matrices with lots of zeroes" because the matrix structure -- the organization into rows AND columns -- is completely irrelevant to the problem. By the way, when you say that the $c_i$s cannot be zero, do you mean that none of them is zero, or that at least one is nonzero?

Comment: Ok, I see your point! And for your other question, I meant that none of the $c_i$'s can be zero.

Comment: Ah..."none of them zero" sounds nasty to me...but this really isn't my niche, so don't read anything into that.